# multiple csv to one takes long time?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv

I tried each line to measure the time taken, as a result more time is taken while appdending and concatenating the csv files, is there any other methods to reduce the time taken?

```
source = "C:\\"  # 
destination = "C:\\"  
zip_files = [f for f in glob.iglob(source + '/*/*.zip', recursive=True)]


def main(item):
    print(item.split('.')[0])
    dir_name = item.split('.')[0]
    with zipfile.ZipFile(item, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(dir_name)
        combined_csv_start = time.perf_counter()
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(dir_name + '/*.csv')]
    c_csv = []
    for filename in all_filenames:
        **c_csv.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
    combined_csv = pd.concat(c_csv)**
    remove_source_path = item.split(source)[1]
    remove_zip_extension = remove_source_path.split('.zip')[0]
    save_filename = '_'.join(remove_zip_extension.split('\\'))[1:]
    save_filepath = os.path.join(destination, f"{save_filename}.csv")
    save_to_csv_start = time.perf_counter()
    combined_csv.to_csv(save_filepath, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as exe:
        for file in zip_files:
            exe.submit(main, file)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you regard as a long time. Pandas should be pretty good at pulling things into memory, but doing that seems like an unnecessary and potentially very expensive operation if all you want is to append one line at a time without any additional processing.

Comment: @tripleee: seems that the files are stored in a zip archive.

Comment: Are you really trying to perform this with concurrent tasks ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Still pulling them all into memory just so you can _then_ write the combination to disk is just a waste of memory.

Comment: And yes, agree; throwing multiprocessing at an I/O-bound task is only likely to add congestion rather than speed things up.

Comment: @tripleee: can you append the files without decompressing ??

Comment: No, but you can decompress one by one into memory and write a line at a time to conserve memory.